# Angular material matTable: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'template')

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-table

I am working with angular material matTable and I always get this type of error in the console:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'template')
   at MatHeaderRowDef.extractCellTemplate
```

This my code:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="numero">
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns">
      <mat-header-cell title="Numero" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Numero</mat-header-cell>
    </mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
       <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{item.numero}}</mat-cell>
    </mat-row>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="amount">
     <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns">
       <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Amount</mat-header-cell>
      </mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
        <mat-cell  *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.amount}} </mat-cell>
      </mat-row>
   </ng-container>
</table>
```

Comment: which version of angular material are you using?

Comment: I am using angular 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, mat-header-row and mat-row are placed as an immediate child element of the table element, you can try the below code

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows="true" matSort>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="numero">
      <mat-header-cell title="numero" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> numero</mat-header-cell>
       <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{item.numero}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="amount">
       <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> amount</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.amount}} </mat-cell>
   </ng-container>

   <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
   <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
   <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['numero'];"></mat-row>
   <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['amount'];"></mat-row>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error happened to me when I accidently commented the `td` as below

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
  <!-- <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td> -->
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Yep. I didn't define a TH (since I didn't want headers in the table) and same error ocurred. You must have both TH and TD defined in the template.

Answer (score 0):

You define your structure in a weird way. You should define columns in this way:

- Firstly **matColumn**
- Inside matColumn: **matHeaderCellDef** and **matCellDef**

  ```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  ```

At after the column definitions you should define the **matHeaderRowDef** and **matRowDef** inside mat-table:

```
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

You can find many examples there: https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

Comment: i already did that and it always gives me this error     ```Missing definitions for header, footer, and row; cannot determine which columns should be rendered.
    at getTableMissingRowDefsError      ```